# ModelBuilder Speed. Runs very Slow

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, arcgis-pro

I've built out a model but it takes what feels like a very long time to run. About 60 seconds for each iteration and I only have 200 records. I am not sure what is normal or expected for these types of things? No tool in particular is drastically slower than the others, it's just all slow. I also feel like just a couple days ago virtually identical model was running much faster. It gets slower every day.

Does anyone have guidance on how to improve processing speed or are there other things in the background aside from the model itself that drastically slow this done? Looking to do anything I reasonably can to speed this up.

I've even tried coding some of it in ArcPy just using the same tools, testing out what might work. It ran even slower.

[image]

Attached is an image of the ModelBuilder and here is a list of the tools:

1) Active: Point Feature Class, approx 200 records

2) Iterates through each point

3) Pairwise Intersection to Identify the corresponding Parcel Record

4) Buffer .5 Mile Out

5) Intersect with Roads and School Zone polygon

6) Select which polygon layer the Selected Feature does not exist in (invert selection)

7) Delete the other polygons

8) Clip all other parcels that fall within our remaining polygon

9) Finish

In a nutshell identifying all parcels around a subject parcel that are within the same school zone and do not cross particular highways.

Comment: Iterating Select By Location can be slow. Maybe you can replace this with one Spatial Join?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slowness can be caused by many things and may not even have anything to do with your model, for example your network is slowing down for some reason, or there is not enough space on your hard disk if you are writing locally?

So basically no one will be able to answer this question as no one can observe the performance.

That said there are a few top tips to speed things up:

- If any of your input data is a shapefile make sure it has a spatial index, even better move it into a file geodatabase.
- If you are using queries to select data then add an attribute index to the field you are querying.
- Write intermediate data to IN_MEMORY. It appears you are using ArcGIS Pro, if you have the latest version then use [memory](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/the-in-memory-workspace.htm) instead

Following these top tips you'll at least know that you have fine tuned your model to run as fast as it can and any slowness is probably down to some other system issue or quirkiness with the data.

Comment: OK using intermediate data MEMORY is an absolute game changer. Probably increased speed 10 fold without altering anything else. I will report back on the other solutions. @hornbydd thanks a ton!!!!

Comment: Typically when writing data to in memory your output would be something like `memory\myTempData` for the new ArcPro. Think of it as a simple geodatabase so it can only hold simple featureclasses and tables (so not domains, networks, relationships etc...)

Comment: Understood. As I run this more it keeps slowing down again. Do I need to clear or reset the memory or anything like that?